# Sorting list of nested dictionaries by value inside of a list

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

```
[OrderedDict([('id', 1), ('events', [OrderedDict([('id', 4), ('timestamp', '2018-01-19T15:47:56.587126Z')]),
                                     OrderedDict([('id', 5), ('timestamp', '2018-01-19T15:47:56.587761Z')])])]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 2), ('events', [OrderedDict([('id', 6), ('timestamp', '2018-01-19T15:47:56.588413Z')])])])]
```

I'm trying to sort using

```
sorted(my_list, key=lambda e: e['events'][0]['timestamp'], reverse=True)
```

but this only works when the list under 'events' has length one. If I do reverse=False I get the correct ordering (just backwards) but I need it by most recent timestamp

Edit:

The sort I'm trying to get would have timestamps in this order:

```
('timestamp', '2018-01-19T15:47:56.588413Z')
('timestamp', '2018-01-19T15:47:56.587761Z')
('timestamp', '2018-01-19T15:47:56.587126Z')
```

Comment: see the below answer. I'm trying to get most recent timestamp to oldest. I can get oldest to newest using what I have but if I reverse the list to get newest to oldest it changes the orders around

Comment: Are you trying to sort by the latest timestamp?  Please post excepted result.

Comment: Are you only interested in timestamps or the output shown in my post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you wish to reverse the list of OrderedDicts as well as reverse any  nested lists.  We can do this by recreating the list in reverse.

**Code**

```
def reversed_nested_list(lst):
    """Return a reversed list of shallow nested OrderedDicts."""
    main_lst = []
    for od in lst[::-1]:
        replaced = ct.OrderedDict()
        for k, v in od.items():
            if not isinstance(v, list):
                replaced[k] = v
            else:
                replaced[k] = v[::-1]
        main_lst.append(replaced)
    return main_lst


reversed_nested_list(my_list)
```

Output

```
[OrderedDict([('id', 2),
              ('events',
               [OrderedDict([('id', 6),
                             ('timestamp',
                              '2018-01-19T15:47:56.588413Z')])])]),
 OrderedDict([('id', 1),
              ('events',
               [OrderedDict([('id', 5),
                             ('timestamp', '2018-01-19T15:47:56.587761Z')]),
                OrderedDict([('id', 4),
                             ('timestamp',
                              '2018-01-19T15:47:56.587126Z')])])])]
```

Since your events were already inserted in temporal order, we can simply iterate the main list and reassign any nested lists in reverse.